# O que há de errado nesse código?

Tags: java

Meu professor da faculdade nos passou esse código e foi questionado o que há de errado:

```
public class Teste {
    private static Teste INSTANCE = null;

    public static Teste getInstance()
    {
        if ( INSTANCE == null )
        {
            INSTANCE = new Teste();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private Teste() {
    }
}
```

Eu cheguei a conclusão foi que:

1. Teste nunca será criado.
2. O getInstance vai retornar "Lixos".
3. Como o construtor está privado ele nunca será chamado.
4. Mais de uma instância teste pode ser criada

Seria isso?

Comment: `Como o construtor está privado ele nunca será chamado.` esta conclusáo nao esta correta, se o construtor é privado, ele só é acessivel dentro da propria classe.

Comment: Suas 4 conclusões estão erradas.

Comment: 1. Identação fora do padrão Java :D. 2. Singleton é considerado por muitos um *anti-pattern*  3. Muito provavelmente o que seu professor está procurando: Está versão não é *Thread-safe* e pode acabar criando instâncias diferentes de `Teste` em um ambiente concorrente. Minha pergunta no SOen (em inglês) discute algumas das soluções clássicas para *concurrent lazy-loading*: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6189099/664577

Comment: O maior problema aí é a pergunta feita. O código não tema nada de errado. Se além do código o professor tivesse passado que ele rodaria em situação que poderia ser criado concorrentemente e qual é o problema de *design* deste código, aí daria para responder melhor. Quando a pergunta é ruim, a resposta fica complicada. Por isso que é comum os programadores sofrerem para criar as soluções, antes de solucionar precisa saber bem qual é o problema, precisa fazer a pergunta certa. (não estou falando desta pergunta posta aqui, que está boa para um iniciante, apesar das conclusões erradas)

Comment: Considerando a resposta que você aceitou, leia isso: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema do código é que se houver mais de uma chamada concorrente no primeiro acesso ao método `getInstance()` ele pode criar duas instâncias de Teste.

A solução básica para isso é sincronizar o método:

```
public static synchronized Teste getInstance()
{
    if ( INSTANCE == null )
    {
        INSTANCE = new Teste();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

O problema desta abordagem é que todas as chamadas estarão sujeitas a bloqueios, deixando a execução geral do programa mais lenta. Imagine um método assim num servidor de aplicação com vários usuários acessando o sistema? É terrível.

Uma solução melhor seria um bloco `synchronized` dentro do `IF`:

```
public static Teste getInstance()
{
    if ( INSTANCE == null ) {
      synchronized (Teste.class) {
        INSTANCE = new Teste();
      }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

Isso resolve o problema da sincronização em todos os acessos, mas é uma solução "ingênua", pois na verdade voltamos ao problema inicial. Como o `IF` não está sincronizado, duas `threads` diferentes podem entrar no `IF` ao mesmo tempo e, mesmo com a sincronização, elas retornarão instâncias diferentes quando `INSTANCE` for `null`.

Então, a solução mais "pura" para o singleton pattern seria acrescentar uma verificação dupla, assim:

```
public static Teste getInstance()
{
    if ( INSTANCE == null ) {
      synchronized (Teste.class) {
        if ( INSTANCE == null ) {
          INSTANCE = new Teste();
        }
      }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

Com essa última abordagem, garantimos que não haverá perda de desempenho por causa de sincronização desnecessária do método inteiro.

Além disso, garantimos que, mesmo que duas chamadas concorrentes ao método entrem dentro do primeiro `IF`, daí temos uma nova verificação sincronizada que garante uma única instância de Teste.

Então, no pior caso, se houver duas ou mais chamadas concorrentes no primeiro acesso a `getInstance` (quando `INSTANCE` ainda é `null`), apenas estas primeiras chamadas serão sincronizadas, sendo que após a primeira atribuição de `INSTANCE`, nenhuma chamada posterior será sincronizada.

Uma leitura completa sobre isso você encontra no

> Head First Design Patterns.

Recomendo que pesquise sobre [Singleton](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton)

Nota: o construtor `private` impede que qualquer outra classe crie inadvertidamente ou arbitrariamente uma instância indesejada de Teste.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, consegui entender a questão.

Comment: A não ser que algo tenha mudado no Java 8 / 9, sem o uso de *volatile* você pode enfrentar problemas mesmo com os dois ifs e o bloco *synchronized* (para mais detalhes veja: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java), eu mesmo já sofri com um objeto parcialmente inicializado no passado. Uma alternativa possível é o seguinte idioma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar injeção de dependência então?

Comment: -1 por recomendar *Double-Checked Locking* quebrado: Leia isso: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html